# Stone–Čech Compactification always exists?

Tags: algebraic-topology, compactification

i have a question regarding the Stone–Čech compactification of some topological space.

On Wikipedia Page, it says "A form of the axiom of choice is required to prove that every topological space has a Stone–Čech compactification", but in a lot of texts regarding this, its always stated that a topological space must at least be Tychonoff, in order to have *any* compactification. Whats up with that?

Can anyone confirm or give an explanation on how one can see that any topological Space $X$ can have a Stone–Čech compactification? (Or is Wikipedia just spewing nonsense in this case?)

Comment: Maybe they're operating on different definitions.

Comment: Did you read the entire wikipedia page?  In the section "Universal property and functoriality" there's an answer to the question.  The constructions work for any topological space, but the extra assumptions of complete regularity and Hausdorff are necessary to prove that the S-C compactification has some desired properties in addition to the universal property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) is misleading. The definition is

> The Stone–Čech compactification of the topological space $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space $βX$ together with a continuous map $i_X : X → βX$ that has the following universal property: any continuous map $f : X → K$, where $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space, extends uniquely to a continuous map $βf : βX → K$, i.e. $(βf)i_X = f$.

In the diagram below, however, $i_X$ is depicted as an arrow
$$X \hookrightarrow \beta X$$
which suggests that $i_X$ is an embedding as a subspace. This **is not required** in the definition, although it uses the phrase "$f$ extends to $\beta f$" (normally a map is extended from a subspace to the the total space).

Later Wikipedia correctly states

- The map from $X$ to its image in $βX$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $X$ is Tychonoff.

So what is going on here?

The map $i_X : X → βX$ always has the above universal property (for **arbitrary** $X$), but for non-Tychonoff $X$ it is not a compactification of $X$.

Here is the definition of a [compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)):

> An embedding of a topological space $X$ as a dense subset of a compact space is called a compactification of $X$.

Therefore it is not really adequate to call $i_X : X \to \beta X$ the Stone–Čech **compactification** for arbitrary $X$. Perhaps one should better call it the Stone–Čech map.

**Remark.**

Using the Stone–Čech map, we can prove the following well-known

**Theorem.**  Each topological space $X$ has a *Tychonoffication*. This is a map $p_X : X \to \tau X$ to a Tychonoff space $\tau X$ that has the following universal property: any continuous map $f : X → T$, where $T$ is a Tychonoff space, admits a unique continuous map $\tau f : \tau X → T$ such that $\tau f \circ p_X = f$.

*Proof*. Let $\tau X = i_X(X) \subset \beta X$ and $p_X: X \xrightarrow{i_X} \tau X$. Let $\iota_X \tau X \to \beta X$ denote inclusion. Given any continuous map $f : X \to T$ to a Tychonoff space, we know that there exists a unique continuous map $\phi : X \to \beta T$ such that $\phi \circ i_X = i_T \circ f$. We have $$\phi(\tau X) = \phi(i_X(X)) = i_T(f(X)) \subset i_T(T) = \tau T .$$
Since $\iota_T$ is an embedding, we get a continuous map
$$\tau f = \iota_T^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \iota_X : \tau X \xrightarrow{\phi} \tau T \xrightarrow{i_T^{-1}} T .$$
Then
$$\tau f \circ p_X = \iota_T^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \iota_X \circ p_X =  \iota_T^{-1} \circ \phi \circ i_X = i_T^{-1} \circ i_T \circ f = f .$$

Let $\psi : \tau X \to T$ be any map such that $\psi \circ p_X = f$. We get

$$i_T \circ \psi \circ p_X = i_T \circ f = \phi \circ i_X = i_T \circ i_T^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \iota_X \circ p_X = i_T \circ \tau f \circ p_X .$$

Since $i_T$ is injective, we get $\psi \circ p_X = \tau f \circ p_X$. Since $p_X$ is surjective, we get $\psi = \tau f$. $\phantom{xx}\square$